# Master Data Services Transferring data

Tags: sql, sql-server, master-data-services, mds

I'm new to MDS and I am trying to figure out if there is a way to transfer data from the UI to SQL. I saw you can transfer data from sql server using the job MDS_DataBase Name_Sync but I cant find anything that transfers data from MDS. When I check my stg tables are completely empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you enter any data from MDS UI it gets stored in the mdm tables in MDM database. To get that data outside, you need to create Subscription Views and through ETL(SSIS or any other tool.) you can pull up that data.